# file_get_contents failing

Tags: php, api, curl, file-get-contents, tumblr

I have a blog on tumblr, and I'm trying to access it via php and tumblrs api.

the api endpoint is:

```
http://blog.example.com/api/read/json?start=0&num=10&debug=1
```

and that seems to work fine.

However, when I do:

```
$result = file_get_contents("http://blog.example.com/api/read/json?start=0&num=10&debug=1");

print_r($result);
```

the browser outputs

```
Warning:  file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /path/to/file/test.php on line 5

Warning:  file_get_contents(http://blog.example.com/api/read/json?start=0&num=10&debug=1) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /path/to/file/test.php on line 5
```

This also fails with Curl.

Ideas?

I think this has something to do with the fact that my blog is on a subdomain. The reason I say this, is, if I run the same script on a blog located on the root url, it works fine. Is there a correct way to escape subdomains?

Comment: What message does curl fail with? (use `curl_error()`  to output it)

Comment: It means that `willium.com` is most likely not being resolved by the machine you're running this script on.

Comment: I think this has something to do with the fact that my blog is on a subdomain. The reason I say this, is, if I run the same script on a blog located on the root url, it works fine. Is there a correct way to escape subdomains?

Comment: Do you have it with your domain? Or what if you use BLOGNAME.tumblr.com. Will it work?

Comment: I can't access the url. Maybe DNS is broke? What about a fixed IP address?

Comment: @jose adrian yes, but that does not work either.

Comment: Tumblr has a new Api [Tumblr API](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2)

Comment: @matthecat nope, it works just fine.

Comment: Not for me, so it isn't working fine =P (tried with chrome 13, IE9 and firefox 6)

Comment: @Jose that was it :) The new API worked brilliantly. Go ahead and make that an answer.

Comment: I deleted the answer because i thought you said it didn't work ... haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New Tumblr API: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2

If you have your domain with your tumblr account it will work. An [example](http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/dandoporculo.com/posts/text?api_key=PyezS3Q4Smivb24d9SzZGYSuhMNPQUhMsVetMC9ksuGPkK1BTt&notes_info)

Comment: I know, that was weird, that the old API works, but didn't work when I used it from a script. Very odd. Nonetheless, this worked!

Answer (score 2):

This code is failing because the DNS lookup is failing.  This could be because your server is having trouble contacting its name servers.  Or its because `blog.example.com`  doesn't exist (it fails in my browser so it should fail everywhere).  You could try changing your name servers to google's: 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4.  These DNS servers work well.

Comment: if you think I own blog.example.com you're crazy ;)

Comment: @willium yeah but are you trying to grab a domain that doesn't exist?  Because your server can't resolve the domain name.   Its really obvious.

Comment: To confirm that the issue is the domain not existing (which it should be, however there may be more issues), try to do the file_get_contents on something such as google.com. If it fails to resolve, you have an issue with your DNS somewhere along the line. However, I think the more likely issue is that blog.example.com simply doesn't exist. If you used a different domain and changed it for this question, that may not be the problem.

Comment: @FuzziBear well nothing exists at google.com,  that redirects to www.google.com.  curl will redirect.  you shouldn't be using file_get_contents() like this,  its insecure and a poor design.